# Passing value from onPostExecute to onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a query running to collect a youtube id from a database.  The **AsyncTask** works and I get the piece of information but I can't pass it from onPostExecute to onCreate.

Here is what I have tried doing.

1. Make `youtubeIdCode` a global variable.
2. Run the query to get the id from the database.
3. Return the youtubeid in doInBackground.
4. Set youtubeIdCode = the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute.
5. Try calling the `youtubeIdCode` in onCreate to see if the result from onPostExecute passed to youtubeIdCode.  This is where I have the issue.  It is not passing from onPostExecute to onCreate.  How can I pass it because in onCreate is where I will be needing the id to form a youtube url.

   ```
   //Activity needs added to manifest.
   public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   //LOG tag for debugging
   private static final String TAG = "GalleryActivity";

   String youtubeIdCode;

   //Override on Create and set contentView to new activity_details layout.
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
       //Log for debugging so we can tell if activity started successfully.
       Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
       youtubeIdCode = "";

       loadMovieData();
       String test = "The value is" + youtubeIdCode;
       Log.v("youtube code test", test);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("movie");

       String image = movie.getMoviePoster();
       String title = movie.getTitle();
       String releaseDate = movie.getDate();
       String voteAverage = movie.getVoteAverage();
       String plot = movie.getPlot();

       ImageView poster = findViewById(R.id.details_image);
       Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(poster);

       TextView name = findViewById(R.id.details_title);
       name.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.movie_title)) + " " + title);

       TextView dateRelease = findViewById(R.id.details_release_date);
       dateRelease.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.release_date)) + " " + releaseDate);

       TextView averageVote = findViewById(R.id.details_voter_average);
       averageVote.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.vote_average)) + " " + voteAverage);

       TextView moviePlot = findViewById(R.id.details_plot);
       moviePlot.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.plot)) + " " + plot);

   }

   public class FetchTrailer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           final String YOUTUBE_ID = "id";
           final String RESULTS = "results";
           String youtubeId = " ";

           Intent intent = getIntent();
           Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("movie");
           String id = movie.getID();

           final URL trailerUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrlTrailer(id);
           Log.v("Built trailer url", trailerUrl.toString());

           try {
               String jsonResponse = NetworkUtils.getReponseFromHttpUrl(trailerUrl);

               JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

               JSONArray resultsArray = moviesObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

               for(int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i ++){
                   JSONObject movieObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   youtubeId = movieObject.getString(YOUTUBE_ID);
                   Log.v("youtubeid", youtubeId);
               }

           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return youtubeId;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           youtubeIdCode = s;
           Log.v("onposttest", s);
       }
   }

   //Tell the new method to get the data based on the search term within the url.
   private void loadMovieData() {
       //If there is a network connection, fetch the data.
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
               activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
       if (isConnected) {
           new FetchTrailer().execute();
       } else {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_internet_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.show();
       }
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rethink the logic of the app. The main idea of using an `AsyncTask` is that the main thread would not block while the task is running.

This means `onCreate()` shouldn't wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish to continue it's execution, which is what you are implying that should happen.

The way to think your app, is that the URL setup you want to do with the youtube id, and any aditional processing should be trigged by `onPostExecute()` when the task is finished.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response.  I am still not sure what to do though.  What would be the best way to get the variable from the database?

Comment: If it is the internal sqlite dabatabase just run a query to retrieve the value. If you are getting it from a remote location, what ever you do with the id, you have to do it in a method called inside onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a setter of the var you need to put te value, then onPostExecute just call that setter function and pass the value of the var in the AsyncTask, and after that use a method to fetch the text on your widgets, if you do it before you pass the value it will be null.

Also try to do AsyncTask in a separate class

AsyncTask OnPostExecute

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ListaLineal> superlistItems) {
        super.onPostExecute(superlistItems);


        activity.setSuperListItems(superlistItems); -> this retrieve the value of a list that I was using (I got the value of the list in doInBackground)
        activity.setupData(); -> method for setting up data
    }
```

In your case setupData will look similar to this

```
 public void setupData(){
 String image = movie.getMoviePoster();
    String title = movie.getTitle();
    String releaseDate = movie.getDate();
    String voteAverage = movie.getVoteAverage();
    String plot = movie.getPlot();

    ImageView poster = findViewById(R.id.details_image);
    Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(poster);

    TextView name = findViewById(R.id.details_title);
    name.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.movie_title)) + " " + title);

    TextView dateRelease = findViewById(R.id.details_release_date);
    dateRelease.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.release_date)) + " " + releaseDate);

    TextView averageVote = findViewById(R.id.details_voter_average);
    averageVote.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.vote_average)) + " " + voteAverage);

    TextView moviePlot = findViewById(R.id.details_plot);
    moviePlot.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.plot)) + " " + plot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a time of call asynTask you can do like that, may be it work i am not confident.

```
new FetchTrailer(){
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
     super.onPostExecute(o);
  }
}.execute()
```